# php if else confusion with html

Tags: php, html

i am having problem trying to sort this php code with html output text it is only excuting the false route..e.g.opps text message..

why is this happening, my syntax seems to be ok, no errors encountered...thanks in advance...singhy

```
<body>

<?php if (isset($success) && $success):?>
<h3>success message here.</h3> 
<?php else:?>
<h2>Oops!</h2>
<h3>Sorry, there was a problem, please try again.</h3>
<?php endif;?>

</body>
```

Comment: Can't understand what you asking for?

Comment: What is `$success`?  It is false or not set.

Comment: Maybe `$success` isn't set?

Comment: It doesn't really matter if it is set or not in his case. From what it sounds, both the success and failure message are showing and syntax wise they shouldn't. Only one should show, either by success being set+true or false.

Comment: Once again - what is the value of `$success`?

Comment: thanks , i have a webform in a seperate webpage, the field has data in it, and a button submit, once this is set it goes to thank you webpage from where this is if else lives, and i want to display the success message to say that email will be sent to user otherwise an error message is displayed (oppps message)

Comment: Still not showing where `$success` is set/initialized..

Comment: The code you posted is correct. The problem is probably with how you're setting `$success`. You need to show more of the code to diagnose this.

Comment: $success = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); is set earlier on ...

Comment: Not familiar with the if else endif syntax you are using but add a space after your : on the if and else. Any example i've found had the added white space.

Comment: hi mario yes you are right i want to display success and it seem to show the opps message !

Comment: add var_dump($success); exit(); prior to your conditional and post your result for everybody

Comment: Is $success set earlier on on the SAME PAGE or on the form page that is then redirected to the Thank You page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right.
Syntax in your code is ok, but the logic of the program is wrong (perhaps).

You are using the [PHP's mail() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).
Ok.

Say you got this form:

**my_web_form.html**

```
<form action="form_processor.php" method="post">
    To:<input type="text" name="to"><br><br>
    Subject:<input type="text" name="subject"><br><br>
    Message:<textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea><br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Data sent through this form, need to be processed by `form_processor.php`

The most basic script in the universe to handle this processing, could be:

**form_processor.php file:**

```
<?php
isset($_POST['to']) ? $to = $_POST['to'] : $to = null;
isset($_POST['subject']) ? $subject = $_POST['subject'] : $subject = null;
isset($_POST['message']) ? $message = $_POST['message'] : $message = null;

if ($to && $subject && $message) {

    // Set your headers
    $raw_headers = array(
                   'From: your@email.tld',
                   'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion()
                   // Another header
                   // Another header
                   // Another header
                   );

    $headers = implode("\r\n", $raw_headers);

    $success = mail($to, $subject, wordwrap($message, 70), $headers);

    if ($success) {

        echo "<h3>Email Successfuly Sent!</h3>\n";

    }

} else {

    echo "<h2>Oops!</h2>\n";
    echo "<h3>Sorry, there was a problem, please try again.</h3>\n";

}
?>
<br><br>
<a href="my_web_form.html">Back</a>
```

In fact, there's no need to use `$success`
You can use the `mail()` function inside your `if()` expression, since `mail()` returns `true` on success.

```
if (mail($to, $subject, wordwrap($message, 70), $headers)) {
    // Success message
}
```

As I mentioned, this code snippet is the most basic script. Obviously you need to sanitize the code, validate variables, tidy up the code, etc. But now, you got a starting point.

Comment: hi klymax sorry about late response, thanks for the detailed script logic, thanks will try it out, thanks again...singhy

Comment: Remember: **don't use this code as-is in your live server**, this is just a keyhole so you can see what's going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

This code will always go to false statement since you have you given any  value to $success

Condition:

isset($success) = false;

$success is not set hence not true;

To get to success message you need to initialize and assign true value to variable $success from putting it in if statement.

```
 <body>
        <?php 

    // you need to achieve this somehow in your success criteria function.
        $success = true; 

        if (isset($success) && $success){?>
            <h3>success message here.</h3> 
            <?php } else { ?>
            <h2>Oops!</h2>
            <h3>Sorry, there was a problem, please try again.</h3>
            <?php } ?>

            </body>
```

This code will get you to success message. But you need to set value of $success in your function to make it more practical.

Answer (score -3):

Try

```
if ($success) {
    // Success message here
}
```

Comment: This will cause a notice if the variable isn't set.

Comment: sorry this did not work either have tried in the past see my comment above...